# Pattern name for putting "barriers" between classes

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Sometimes putting a "barrier" between classes can be very helpful in the long run (although it seems a problem at the beginning). For example, in Rails models are not able to call the controller or the views. This helps having clean/testable/flexible code. Is there a name for this?

For example, when all the classes have references to other classes and are able to send messages to them, you end with code that is coupled.

Comment: Law of Demeter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks dbugger. I apply the law of Demeter in views. I never do something like a.b().c() in a view, but a.bc(). But what I am trying to describe is the case when there is no way to get from A to C from design.

Comment: That is often language dependent, but one way is to build things in different physical deployment units and only expose certain classes and methods publicly.

Comment: Separation of Concerns?  Encapsulation? Multitier architecture? It depends on what level of abstraction you're putting the barrier.

Comment: It is probably separation of concerns... but I am a bit suprised that there is not a (very) specific term for this